# States and positive elements in $C^*$-algebras

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra and $w$ be a state (i.e a positive linear functional such that $\|w\|=w(1_A)=1$. I'm trying to prove the following:
a) if $a$ is selfadjoint and $w(a^2)=w(a)^2$ then for any $b\in A$ we have $w(ab)=w(a)w(b)=w(ba)$.
b) if $\|a\|\le 1$ and  $T=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1_A & a  \\
a^* & 1_A \\
\end{array} \right) $ then $T$ is positive.
What I have done:

for part a) I proved that for any $a\in A$ we have $|w(a)|\le w(|a|^2)^\frac{1}{2}$ and I know that for any state we can define a semi inner product as follows $<a,b>=w(b^*a)$ but I cant get the result I want.

for part b) it is clear that $T$ is selft adjoint, so if $\sigma(T)\subset[0,\infty)$ then $T$ is positive, I'm not sure how to find the spectrum of $T$.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For a):** as you recalled, we have Cauchy-Schwarz for $w(x^*y)$, i.e.
$$
|w(x^*y)|^2\leq w(x^*x)w(y^*y)\quad\forall x,y\in A.
$$
Now for every $b$ in $A$
$$
w(ab)-w(a)w(b)=w((a-w(a)1)b)=w(a'b)\quad\mbox{with}\quad a'=a-w(a)1.
$$
Note that $a'$ is self-adjoint and $a'^*a'=a'^2=a^2-2w(a)a+w(a)^21$. Hence $w(a'^2)=w(a^2)-w(a)^2=0$ by assumption. Therefore, by Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$
|w(a'b)|^2\leq w(a'^*a')w(b^*b)= w(a'^2)w(b^*b)=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad w(a'b)=w(ab)-w(a)w(b)=0$$
for every $b\in A$. It follows that $w(ab)=w(a)w(b)$, and we can show in a similar fashion that $w(ba)=w(b)w(a)$.

**For b):** observe the matrix identity
$$
(I-T)^*(1-T)=\left(\matrix{0&-a\\-a^*&0}\right)\left(\matrix{0&-a\\-a^*&0}\right)=\left(\matrix{aa^*&0\\0&a^*a}\right).
$$
It follows that $\|I-T\|^2=\|(I-T)^*(I-T)\|=\max\{\|aa^*\|,\|a^*a\|\}=\|a\|^2$.

If $\|a\|\leq 1$, we get $\|I-T\|\leq 1$, so $T=I-(I-T)$ is positive.

Comment: Hi Julien, thank your for the hints, is it ture that a diagonal matrix is positive if the elements of the diagonal are positive, I ask this because of the last matrix in the decomposition, and is it possible to compute the eigenvalues some how and then decide? thank you again.

Comment: Oh, I see, perfect! :)

Comment: Perfect, any ideas about a)?

Comment: Don't be, thank you for all the help :)

Comment: Note that $w(a)$ is a real number and you have proved that $|w(a)|^2\leq w(|a|^2)$, and now the equality holds, and I believe this can happen only when $a=w(a)Id$.

Comment: @ougao, thank you but I can't see why this is true, I mean if the equality holds, how we can prove that $a$ must have this form ??

Comment: @ougao The result does not rely on proving that $a$ must be scalar. This is false. Consider $w:M_2(\mathbb{C})\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ which sends every $2\times 2$ matrix on its $(1, 1)$ coeffcient. Then $w$ is a multiplicative state. And in a particular $w(a^2)=w(a)^2$ for every $a$. Just tale $a$ self-adjoint, non-scalar for a counter-example.

Comment: @i.a.m So I finally figured out a...What do you think?

Comment: @julien, can't thank you enough!

Comment: @i.a.m Oh, you're most welcome!

Comment: @ julien, yes, you are right, I misread $\omega$ as a trace..