# positive linear functionals and states(C* algebras)

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\omega$ be a state of an algebra $A$ .

if $a \in A_{sa} $ (self-adjoint) such that $\omega(a^2)=\omega(a)^2$ then $\omega(ab)=\omega(a)\omega(b)=\omega(ba)$.

I would like to prove this argument for  $b\neq{a}$, but I don't understand how the fact that $\omega(a^2)=\omega(a)^2$ can help me in this case.

Comment: maybe consider $c=(a+b)$. This may be of some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $\omega$ is a positive linear functional on $A$ such that $\omega(a^2)=\omega(a)^2$ for all $a\in A_{sa}$ and $b\in A_{sa}$ is arbitrary.

1. As @SamM suggested expanding both sides of the equality $\omega((a+b)^2)=\omega(a+b)^2$ you will get 
   $$
   \text{Re}\,\omega(ab)=\omega(a)\omega(b).
   $$
2. [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for positive functionals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Positive_functionals_on_C.2A-_and_W.2A-algebras) gives 
   $$
   |\omega(ab)|^2\le\omega(a^2)\omega(b^2)=\bigl(\omega(a)\omega(b)\bigr)^2.
   $$
3. "1+2" gives that $\text{Re}\,\omega(ab)=|\omega(ab)|$, i.e. $\omega(ab)\in\mathbb{R}$ and, hence, $$
   \omega(ba)=\overline{\omega(ab)}=\omega(ab)=\omega(a)\omega(b).
   $$

P.S. We have used that a positive linear functional is self-adjoint, i.e. 
$\omega(x)=\overline{\omega(x^*)}$, and have not used that $\omega$ is a state, i.e. $\|\omega\|=1$.

Comment: actually I can conclude that $b \in A_{sa}$ and therefore $a \in Z(A)$ (center)?

Comment: @letisya Perhaps I misunderstood the assumptions. I *assumed* that $b\in A_{sa}$ and that $\omega(a^2)=\omega(a)^2$ for *all* $a\in A_{sa}$. Isn't that right?

Comment: I am so sorry,I meant that $b\in A$ . I want to prove this argument for all $b\in A$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360872/states-and-positive-elements-in-c-algebras?rq=1

Comment: @letisya Having a unitary algebra helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your help and patience,I really appreciate it :)